# return value from possible type in std::variant through std::visit

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I am trying to wrap my head around `std::variant` and `std::visit` and I am trying to come up with a method to specify a couple of types that I would like my variable to hold (which would go into my `std::variant`) and then retrieve stored data through a `std::visit`. Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

struct PrintType {
  void operator()(const int &data) {
    std::cout << "visiting int node" << std::endl;
  }
  void operator()(const double &data) {
    std::cout << "visiting double node" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct SingleOperatorOverload {
  int operator()(const int &data) {
    std::cout << "visiting int node" << std::endl;
    return data;
  }
};

struct AllTypesOperatorOverload {
  int operator()(const int &data) {
    std::cout << "visiting int node" << std::endl;
    return data;
  }
  double operator()(const double &data) {
    std::cout << "visiting double node" << std::endl;
    return data;
  }
};

int main() {

  using var_t = std::variant<int, double>;

  // print int related operator() content, OK
  var_t foo = 42;
  std::visit(PrintType(), foo);

  // print double related operator() content, OK
  foo = 3.1415;
  std::visit(PrintType(), foo);

  // get value and store into bar, struct with single operator(), OK
  foo = 42;
  auto bar = std::visit(SingleOperatorOverload(), foo);
  std::cout << "bar: " << bar << std::endl;

  // get value and store into bar, struct with multiple operator(), ERROR
  auto bar = std::visit(AllTypesOperatorOverload(), foo);
  std::cout << "bar: " << bar << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The variant is allowed to hold (in this simplified example) either `int` or `double`. If I just want to print something based on the type (as done with the `PrintType` struct), that works fine.

If I want to retrieve data through a visitor as done in the `SingleOperatorOverload` class, which only provides an implementation for the `operator()` accepting an int as a parameter, that works. However, as soon as I try to implement an `operator()` for each type in the `std::variant`, i.e. here `int` and `double`, as in the `AllTypesOperatorOverload` struct, I get a compilation error `error: invalid conversion from '...' {aka double ...} to '...' {aka int ...}` so it seems `std::variant` is handling function signatures differently?

I tried SFINAE but that does not seem to alleviate the problem

```cpp
struct AllTypesOperatorOverload {
  template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value>>
  T operator()(const T &data) {
    std::cout << "visiting int node" << std::endl;
    return data;
  }
  template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, double>::value>>
  T operator()(const T &data) {
    std::cout << "visiting double node" << std::endl;
    return data;
  }
};
```

This will now report an `error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<AllTypesOperatorOverload, int&>'`. Is there a way to provide `operator()` for all types and then receive their respective values into `bar` with the correct type depending on how `foo` has been set? I am aware of `std::get_if<T>()` which may be of use here, but ideally, I don't want to have a long if statement checking for each type, unless absolutely necessary (this is a simplified example, I may want to have several more types in my `std::variant`).

Comment: I wonder if the problem is because double and int can be converted back and forth. Does it reproduce with `std::variant<int*, std::string>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error messages suck, but the issue here is that all of the alternatives of the variant must have the same return type in the visitor. Your `AllTypesOperatorOverload` does not obey this rule, returning a `double` and an `int`, which are not the same type.

The newest versions of [libstdc++ or any version of libc++ produce much better error messages](https://godbolt.org/z/eP4Tdb) that explicitly tell you this (the following is word wrapped by me):

> ```
> error: static_assert failed due to requirement '__visit_rettypes_match'
>     "std::visit requires the visitor to have the same return type for
>      all alternatives of a variant"
>               static_assert(__visit_rettypes_match,
> ```

This makes sense, because when you look at this line, what is the type of `bar`?

```
auto bar = std::visit(AllTypesOperatorOverload(), foo);
```

If you were allowed to return differing types, `bar`'s type would depend on which alternative `foo` holds at runtime. That can't work in C++.

---

Note that there are easier ways to create visitors for `std::visit` that use lambdas instead of externally defined structs. You can use `if constexpr`:

```
std::visit([](auto value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, decltype(value)>) {
        std::cout << "visiting int\n";
    } else {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, decltype(value)>);
        std::cout << "visiting double\n";
    }
    std::cout << "bar: " << value << '\n';
}, foo);
```

Or alternatively, you can define an `overloaded` helper struct that lets you overload lambdas:

```
template <typename... Lambdas>
struct overloaded : Lambdas...
{
    template <typename... Fns>
    explicit constexpr overloaded(Fns&&... fns)
        : Lambdas(std::forward<Fns>(fns))...
    {}

    using Lambdas::operator()...;
};
template <typename... Lambdas>
overloaded(Lambdas...) -> overloaded<Lambdas...>;

// Usage:
std::visit(overloaded{
    [](int value) {
        std::cout << "visiting int\n";
        std::cout << "bar: " << value << '\n';
    },
    [](double value) {
        std::cout << "visiting double\n";
        std::cout << "bar: " << value << '\n';
    }
}, foo);
```

Comment: The full declaration for oevrloaded is only 2 lines long...  `template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;`

Comment: note to self: gcc bad compiler error messages, clang good (well, i knew that, but sometimes i forget to check ...). Printing is fine (but not really my issue here), I am trying to get the value currently stored in `foo` (which can have any type specified in the `std::variant`). Any chance of achieving that?

Comment: @tom "I am trying to get the value currently stored in `foo` (which can have any type specified in the `std::variant`)" The problem is that this doesn't make sense. If you get the value, what would the type of `bar` be? The variant could be either an `int` or a `double`, so `bar`'s type would have to be a superposition of `int` and `double`. That's not allowed. The closest would be to make `bar` a `std::variant<int, double>`, but that leaves us where we started. Instead, you should hoist the code that processes `bar` into the visitor, where it can know the type of what's stored in `foo`.

Comment: @Justin: thanks for the clarification, i'll see if i can make it work this way